# Finding a First Integral of the Lotka-Volterra System

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, systems-of-equations

> For the Lotka-Volterra system below
>   $$\frac{dF}{dt}=-aF+\alpha FR$$
>   $$\frac{dR}{dt}=bR-\beta FR$$
>   show that $V=R^aF^b e^{-\alpha R-\beta F}$ is a first integral, that is, $V(t)$ is constant along any trajectory. What can you conclude about the behaviour of the solutions?

My attempt:

$$\frac{dF}{dt}=-aF+\alpha FR \iff \frac{dF}{-aF+\alpha FR}=dt \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$
$$\frac{dR}{dt}=bR-\beta FR\iff \frac{dR}{bR-\beta FR}=dt \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)$$
Equating $(1)$ and $(2)$
\begin{align} 
\frac{dF}{-aF+\alpha FR}&=\frac{dR}{bR-\beta FR} \\
\int \frac{b}{F}-\beta \ dF&=\int -\frac{a}{R}+\alpha \ dR \\
\ln|F^b|+\ln|R^a|&=\alpha R+\beta F+C \\
F^bR^a&=e^{\alpha R+\beta F}e^C \\
V&=R^aF^be^{-\alpha R-\beta F} \ \ \ \ \ (V=e^C\in\mathbb{R})
\end{align}
Is this a correct method? I do not know what this tells us about the behaiour of the solutions.

Comment: You have a sign mistake  $$\int \frac bF+\beta dF...$$

Answer (score 2):

The question didn't ask you to find a first integral, you just need to verify the one suggested to you. Suppose that we have a solution $(F(t),R(t))$, and consider
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t} V(F(t),R(t)) =\frac{\partial V}{\partial F} \frac{\mathrm{d} F}{ \mathrm{d} t}+\frac{\partial V}{\partial R} \frac{\mathrm{d} R}{\mathrm{d} t}=\left(b R^a F^{b-1}\mathrm{e}^{-\alpha R-\beta F}- \beta R^a F^b \mathrm{e}^{-\alpha R-\beta F} \right)\left(-a F+\alpha F R \right)+\left(a R^{a-1} F^b \mathrm{e}^{-\alpha R-\beta F}-\alpha R^a F^b \mathrm{e}^{-\alpha R-\beta F} \right) \left( bR+\beta FR \right). $$
This is zero if you actually meant to use $-\beta$ (or $-\alpha$) in your original equations.

Comment: Oh I see, we just have to verify this. What exactly does this say about the behaviour of the solutions?

Comment: @Bell I believe $V$ has an extremum point somewhere besides the origin. This means its contour lines near that point are closed, making the solutions periodic.

Comment: Why doesn't $$\frac{\partial V}{\partial F}=R^a(b)F^{b-1}(-\beta)e^{-\alpha R-\beta F}=-\beta b R^aF^{b-1}e^{-\alpha R-\beta F}?$$